# Integrate Google authentication with Python and Dash

Tags: python, authentication, flask, plotly-dash, google-authentication

I'm looking to incorporate Google authentication into a Dash app. I found a very helpful post on working with [Flask here](https://realpython.com/flask-google-login/#creating-a-google-client) that I followed to set up the Google API access and get the authentication screen to appear allowing the user to login with their Google account. Handling the tokens I get in return is where I get lost. It's not clear to me how to access them or use them properly in further callbacks to get the user verified and logged in.

Ultimately, I need to check the verified email against a separate database before allowing access. That end of the pipeline is working, I'm just missing this authentication piece from Google.
Below is a bare-bones example of what I'm trying to do. It will work if you have your [API keys set up with Google](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from flask import redirect, request
from flask_login import logout_user, current_user, LoginManager
import requests
import json
from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationClient
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy import (Table, 
    create_engine, 
    MetaData, 
    String,
    Integer, 
    DateTime, 
    Column)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

import auth_utils

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

server = app.server

# Setup the login manager for the server
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(server)
login_manager.login_view = '/login'

# Set up User class for login manager
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)

# Get secret keys
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = 'your-keys-here'
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'and-here'
client = WebApplicationClient(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)

GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='base-url'),
    dcc.Location(id='login-url', refresh=True, pathname='/login'),
    html.Div(id='hidden-google-redirect-uri',
        style={'display': 'none'}),
    html.Button('Login with Google',
        id='google-login-button',
        n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='login-success-display')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('hidden-google-redirect-uri', 'children'),
    Input('google-login-button', 'n_clicks'),
)
def google_login(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        google_provider_cfg = requests.get(GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL).json()
        google_auth_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["authorization_endpoint"]

        request_uri = client.prepare_request_uri(
            google_auth_endpoint,
            redirect_uri=request.base_url + "/callback",
            scope=["openid", "email", "profile"]
        )
        return dcc.Location(href=request_uri, id='_hidden-google-redirect-uri')
    
    else:
        return html.Div()

@app.callback(
    Output('login-success-display', 'children'),
    Input('google-login-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('hidden-google-redirect-uri', 'children')
)
def google_response(n_clicks, google_response):
    if n_clicks == 0:
        return html.H3('Not logged in.')
    # Get authorization code Google sent back to you
    code = request.args.get("code")

    # Find out what URL to hit to get tokens that allow you to ask for
    # things on behalf of a user
    google_provider_cfg = requests.get(GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL).json()
    token_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["token_endpoint"]

    # Prepare and send a request to get tokens
    token_url, headers, body = client.prepare_token_request(
        token_endpoint,
        authorization_response=request.url,
        redirect_url=request.base_url,
        code=code
    )
    token_response = requests.post(
        token_url,
        headers=headers,
        data=body,
        auth=(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET),
    )

    client.parse_request_body_response(json.dumps(token_response.json()))
    userinfo_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["userinfo_endpoint"]
    uri, headers, body = client.add_token(userinfo_endpoint)
    userinfo_response = requests.get(uri, headers=headers, data=body)

    if userinfo_response.json().get("email_verified"):
        unique_id = userinfo_response.json()["sub"]
        user_email = userinfo_response.json()["email"]
        user_name = userinfo_response.json()["given_name"]
        return html.H3('User verified via Google.')
    else:
        return html.H3('User email not available or not verified by Google.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=8800, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Having faced a similar situation, I ended up using a modified version of [Dash Google OAuth](https://github.com/hossein-jazayeri/dash-google-oauth).

While the library allows the user's name to be accessed via `flask.request.cookies.get('AUTH-USER')`, given the requirement of getting the user's email ID (verified by Google), you could make the following change(s) to the library's `google_auth.py` file:

```py
...

COOKIE_AUTH_USER_EMAIL = 'AUTH-USER-EMAIL'

...

class GoogleAuth(Auth):
    ...
    def login_callback(self):
        ...
        google = self.__get_google_auth(token=token)
        resp = google.get(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_AUTH_USER_INFO_URL'))
            if resp.status_code == 200:
                user_data = resp.json()
                r = flask.redirect(flask.session['REDIRECT_URL'])
                r.set_cookie(COOKIE_AUTH_USER_NAME, user_data['name'], max_age=COOKIE_EXPIRY)
                # Store (Google) verified user's email ID in a cookie
                r.set_cookie(COOKIE_AUTH_USER_EMAIL, user_data['email'], max_age=COOKIE_EXPIRY)
                r.set_cookie(COOKIE_AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN, token['access_token'], max_age=COOKIE_EXPIRY)
                flask.session[user_data['name']] = token['access_token']
                return r
        ...
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def logout():
        r = flask.redirect('/')
        r.delete_cookie(COOKIE_AUTH_USER_NAME)
        # Do not forget to delete your custom cookie
        r.delete_cookie(COOKIE_AUTH_USER_EMAIL)
        r.delete_cookie(COOKIE_AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        return r
```

... and then access the (Google) verified user's email ID via `flask.request.cookies.get('AUTH-USER-EMAIL')` (or whichever value you set for `COOKIE_AUTH_USER_EMAIL`).

Alternatively, if you do not wish to store the user's details (name, email, etc.) in a cookie, you may/could make changes in the above section itself to check the user's email ID against your database before allowing the user access rather than doing so in your `Dash` app's code.

Comment: Hey, I was trying to use this library but I have no idea where to start. Although by following the scarce documentation, I've managed to get to a google oauth screen but logging in just gives a blank json response: `{
  "_error_uris": null, 
  "_translations": null, 
  "state": null
}` 
and I have no idea why. Also, the auth screen just appears (I have not configured the auth anyhow but it still shows up at my base URL).  Could you help?

Comment: @SamarthBhatia While I am not exactly sure as to why you are facing that issue, it might be worth checking and ensuring that the Google OAuth Client has been set up properly on your [Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). In case you have already done so, please ensure that the redirection back from the google auth link back to your site is configured properly.

Comment: How do you add a redirection link? (I have set the `REDIRECT_URL` environment variable and in the Console as well). Also, how do you choose the url at which you want the oauth screen to show up? Thanks for replying btw